# Deciphering & Fixing 'foreign key constraint fails' Error

Tags: mysql, error-handling

I have this mysql query (which add values from a form into a table upon submission). It returns an error message:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customers(customerNumber, customerName, contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, postalCode, country, salesRepEmployeeNumber, creditLimit) VALUES ('$customer_number', '$customer_name', '$last_name', '$first_name', '$phone_number', '$address_1', '$address_2', '$city', '$state', '$postal_code', '$country', '$sales_number', '$credit_limit')";             
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` (`ikb2014_employees`.`customers`, CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`))

I am having a hard time deciphering where the 'foreign key constraint' fails. How can I change the the options in the database for the specific table to that I am able so run the query?

This is what the options in the phpMyAdmin show for the table `employees` and the column `employeeNumber` (assuming that is where the error is being caused).

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
1   employeeNumber int(11)                  No       None   AUTO_INCREMENT
```

I have not worked with a database before so it is hard for me to understand where and why the issue occurs. Any input on how to fix the constraint to properly run the query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A failure of a foreign key constaint means that you are trying to enter data into a column of one table that does not exist in another table. The foreign key constraint is put in place to ensure that the data you insert into the child table exists in the parent table.

In your case, you're attempting to insert (or not attempting to insert) data in to the salesRepEmployeeNumber column of the customers table. In order to successfully do so, you need to ensure that the value that is provided for salesRepEmployeeNumber exists in the employeeNumber column of the employees table.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constraint error is objecting to the value being assigned to the `salesRepEmployeeNumber` column.  The foreign key constraint is checking that the value supplied for that column *matches* a row in `employees` table, it;s looking for a row that has the same value for `employeeNumber`, and it's not finding one.

If you don't want the database to enforce a foreign key constraint, then don't define one.

If you do want the constraint, then that's saying that you have to supply either a valid `employeeNumber` or a `NULL` value for `salesRepEmployeeNumber`.

---

From the code we're seeing, it looks like the SQL statement is vulnerable to SQL Injection. (We're not seeing any guarantees about the values of the variables being incorporated into the SQL text. If any of those values is potentially unsafe, then those values need to be properly escaped, for example, using `mysqli_real_escape_string` function.

A better pattern is to use a **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders**.

Comment: you are right i need to also add the mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

If your foreign key is wrong, you can easily remove it in phpMyAdmin.
Go to the customers table, click on 'structure' tab and at the bottom there will be an +Indexes hidden list, expand it and click DROP on the selected index.

Comment: if i drop the index does that mean I am dropping the whole column or just the foreign key?

Comment: Tried to drio it and it says  #1553 - Cannot drop index 'salesRepEmployeeNumber': needed in a foreign key constraint

Comment: Nevermind, just did ALTER TABLE custimers DROP FOREIGN KEY customers_ibfk_1 and it worked well. thanks for your unput